# How can I prove that the limit doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I have to study the following limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{|xy|})}{x}.$$

I think that this limit does not exist, so I'm trying to prove it. First, I discovered that, if $x=y$, then, the limit is equal to zero. Is there any other variable changing that I can use?

Comment: Why do you think that the limit does not exist? As far as I can tell, the limit is zero.

Comment: Hmmmm. I based myself on another problem. But, can You help me to prove that the limit is zero?

Comment: Write out the Taylor expansion of $\cos$.

Comment: Ok. I gonna try. Thankss!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**

The limit exists and it is zero.
$$(\forall x,y\in \Bbb R)\;\;$$
$$ 1-\cos(\sqrt{|xy|})=2\sin^2(\frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{2})$$
$$\le \frac 12|xy|$$

because
$$(\forall X\in \Bbb R)\;\;|\sin(X)|\le |X|$$

thus, if $ x\ne 0$,
$$|f(x,y)|\le \frac 12|y|$$

Comment: And $|xy| \le (x^2+y^2)/2$.